# Bash: Version number in if statement

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, numbers, decimal-point

Having a hard time passing a **"greater than or equal to"** value in my **if-then-else** statement with a decimal integer ran as a **one-liner** and curling the phpinfo.php page to check if the domain's PHP version is greater than or equal to 7.0. Obviously a php info file (phpinfo.php) is created in the main dir of where site is assigned. Here is my command displayed in human readable:

```
read -ep "Enter the domain: " DOMAIN ; 
PHPVERSION=$(curl -s https://$DOMAIN/phpinfo.php | grep -ioP 'php version\s\K\d.\d') ; 
if [ $PHPVERSION >= 7.0 ] ; 
  then 
    echo -e "PHP version at least 7.0? YES" ; 
  else 
    echo -e "PHP version at least 7.0? NO\nPHP version = $PHPVERSION" ; 
fi ;
```

```
[~]# echo $PHPVERSION
7.0
```

Here are the tests/outputs I use/get when attempting to run the command

**if [ $PHPVERSION >= 7.0 ]**

```
-jailshell: [: 7.0: unary operator expected
PHP version at least 7.0? NO
PHP version = 7.0
```

**if [ $PHPVERSION -ge 7.0 ]**

```
-jailshell: [: 7.0: integer expression expected
PHP version at least 7.0? NO
PHP version = 7.0
```

**if [[ $PHPVERSION >= 7.0 ]]**

```
-jailshell: syntax error in conditional expression
-jailshell: syntax error near `7.0'
```

**if [[ $PHPVERSION -ge 7.0 ]]**

```
-jailshell: [[: 7.0: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".0")
PHP version at least 7.0? NO
PHP version = 7.0
```

I can get it to work just fine as `>` or `-gt` but the PHP version I'm requiring for my test is greater than or equal to 7.0. What am I missing here? I've also tried passing 7.0 as a variable and testing it that way but get the same output on virtually all my tests. I've also tried saving 7.0 as a variable using echo and piping it into `bc` but I don't think I'm doing it right. Also double quotes around variable don't seem to help either. I feel like this is something simple  but I've definitely looked around at all articles I could find on the subject and have yet to come up with anything that works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `7.0` is no [integer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).

Comment: You were close. `[[ $PHPVERSION > 7.0 || $PHPVERSION == 7.0 ]]` is what you're looking for. Within double brackets `>` compares lexicographically, but `>=` doesn't work that way.

Comment: 7 is an integer. 7.0 is not an integer; it is a real number.  Bash does not support operations on real numbers; only operations on integer numbers.

Comment: @oguzismail that was it thank you so much

Comment: The problem is with the number 7.0 is not an integer, it is a float. you have to treat it as a float.